# Is TensorFlow the way to go for this optimization problem?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, optimization

I have to optimize the result of a process that depends on a large number of variables, i.e. a laser engraving system where the engraving depth depends on the laser speed, distance, power and so on.

The final objective is the minimization of the engraving time, or the maximization of the laser speed. All the other parameters can vary, but must stay within safe bounds.

I have never used any machine learning tools, but to my very limited knowledge this seems like a good use case for TensorFlow or any other machine learning library.

I would experimentally gather data points to train the algorithm, test it and then use a gradient descent optimizer to find the parameters (within bounds) that maximize the laser travel velocity.

Does this sound feasible? How would you approach such a problem? Can you link to any examples available online?

Thank you,
Riccardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not quite sure if I understood the problem correctly, would you add some example data and a desired output?

As far as I understood, It could be feasible to use TensorFlow, but I believe there are better solutions to that problem. Let me expand on this.

TensorFlow is a framework focused in the development of Deep Learning models. These usually require lots of data (the number really depends on the problem) but I don’t believe that just you manually gathering this data would be enough unless your team is quite big or already have some data gathered.

Also, as you have a minimization (or maximization) problem given variables that lay within a known range, I think this can be a case of Operations Research optimization instead of Machine Learning. Check this [example](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) of OR.